# What does it mean if $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[X]^2$?

Tags: expected-value

I was wondering if there was any significance to assuming $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[X]^2$? If X is normally distributed, this would correpsonding to it having zero variance (which I guess makes it a dirac delta function, or something similar?)

But is there any other intepretation of this? In particular, if we have three random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ such that $X_1+X_2+X_3=1$, what assumption are we making if we say $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j] = \mathbb{E}[X_i]\mathbb{E}[X_j]$. Is there any context in which doing this can make sense? If $i \neq j$, then that just means $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent (at least for two of the three values of $i,j$, since as the sum is 1, they aren't really all independent). But can it make sense for $i=j$?

For a bit more context, I was thinking in the context of say a system of chemical reaction equations.

You can write down a forward equation that describes the time evolution of the probability distribution. You can then calculate expected values and end up with something that looks like

$$\frac{d\mathbb{E}[X_1]}{dt} = a\mathbb{E}[X_1]+b\mathbb{E}[X_2]+c\mathbb{E}[X_1X_3]+d\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]$$

$$\frac{d\mathbb{E}[X_2]}{dt} = e\mathbb{E}[X_3]+f\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]+g\mathbb{E}[X_2X_3]-h\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]$$

If instead you wrote down a deterministic system for the same system of reactions using the law of mass action, you would arrive at essentially the same system, but without the expected values. But that's comparable to $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]$ being replaced by $\mathbb{E}[X_1]^2$. I was wondering if there was any way of thinking about the relationship between these two in terms variances/ covariances of the random variable?

Comment: Note that the variance of $X$ is $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.

Answer (score 3):

If $E(X^2)=E^2(X)$ then the variance is $0$ and the random variable is actually a constant.

If $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ then the Covariance between them is $0$ which means that they are uncorrelated (but possibly dependent!)

Answer (score 1):

The condition for equality in Holder's /Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says $E[X^{2}]=(EX)^{2}$ only if $X$ is a constant random variable.

If $E[X_iX_j]=(EX_i)( EX_j)$ for all $i$ and $j$ then each $X_i$ is a constant.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added a bit more context to the problem, if you're able to provide any insight on it (though I appreciate that may not be possible!)